# Testing from iOS app through PHP API to database

Tags: php, ios, unit-testing, automated-tests, integration-testing

I am developing an iOS app, which stores data that the user enters in the app through an API written in PHP (using the Yii framework) in a database on a server. It works, however, I don't have any test code. I am looking into the best way to test this kind of program stack, but I cannot see the wood for the trees.

1. For unit testing the PHP API, I am looking into PHPUnit, which seems
   to be the de facto standard for PHP. Is there a standard for unit
   testing iOS code?
2. What would be the best way to create an
   integration test case, in which I specify certain behavior in the
   app, and check if the data ends up correctly in the database?